Using Playwright to automate an Electron executable C#
We are currently looking at some tools to automate an Electron application that is an executable and perform E2E tests(at least that's the goal). All our tests are written in C#.
I have so far tried Selenium with specific version of Chrome driver that's compatible with the app which works. I was able to launch the executable by setting a binary path and interreacting with page elements and etc. Only thing is calling driver.quit doesn't seem to kill the application.
I was looking at alternative such as Playwright which I have zero experience with. I have setup a sample project from their documentation. However this is where I'm getting a bit confused.
Is it possible to launch an executable through Playwright? Playwright is providing "experimental" functionality to test Electron apps. Do I need access to the Electron application's source code to make use of it? I'm not too familiar with other languages other than C#/Java, so I might not be making much sense of it.

You should be able to use the web server functionality to launch it, but it'll need access to the source code: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-webserver
